# Convert PHP closing tag into comment

Tags: php, regex, tags, comments

One of the lines in my script contains a PHP closing tag inside a string. Under normal operation this does not cause a problem, but I need to comment out the line.

I have tried to comment out this line with `//`, `/*` `*/` and `#` but none of them work, the parser considers closing tag to be an actual closing tag.

Here is the line in question:

```
$string = preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>(?:\s*<br\s*/?>)+#i', '<br />', $string);
//                              ^^             ^^
```

What can I do to comment out the above line?

Comment: Funny problem, but real. I vote up.

Comment: OMG. At first i was skeptical of your question, ready to ask what was the problem, but then i tried to comment a line with a string containing '?>' and i got it. This should be added to the long list of http://phpsadness.com

Comment: The usefulness of such a "feature" is explained in http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php, it's useful in case of one-liner `<?php # echo 'simple';?>`.

Comment: @lolesque Thanks for that link. A good one. A related one which covers other languages as well: http://wiki.theory.org/YourLanguageSucks

Comment: if it is only one line, comment out using //

Comment: @YounElan: think twice: that won't work because of the ?> in the string...

Comment: In the first place: Why would you parse HTML documents with a regex? There's no HTML parser written in PHP?

Comment: @OndraŽižka all he's doing is removing repeated br tags. a regex works fine for that. Just because it's bad sometimes doesn't mean it's bad all the time.

Comment: In fairness to PHP, `<script>` tags in HTML have a similar weakness, leading to workarounds like `"</scr" + "ipt>"`.

Comment: You shouldn't comment out code, its bad practice.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Use a trick: concatenate the string from two pieces. This way, the closing tag is cut in two, and is not a valid closing tag anymore. `'?>' --> '?'.'>'`

In your code:

```
$string = preg_replace('#<br\s*/?'.'>(?:\s*<br\s*/?'.'>)+#i', '<br />', $string);
```

This will make `//` comments work.

For `/* */` comments to work, you'd have to split the `*/` sequence too:

```
$string = preg_replace('#<br\s*'.'/?'.'>(?:\s*<br\s*'.'/?'.'>)+#i', '<br />', $string);
```

Remember, sometimes, even though the whole is *more* than the sum of its parts - but being greedy is bad, there are times you are better left with *less*. :)

Comment: @ppeterka Wow, I didn't even think about that. Thank you.

Comment: I had to use this trick in C 2 days ago for a string containing `??<`

Comment: Great one. Why I never think that way!?

Answer (score 73):

**The easiest way**

Create a separate variable to hold your regular expression; this way you can simply comment out the `preg_replace()` statement:

```
$re = '#<br\s*/?>(?:\s*<br\s*/?>)+#i';
// $string = preg_replace($re, '<br />', $string);
```

**Fix using character classes**

To fix line comments, you can break up `?>` by putting `>` inside a character class like so:

```
$string = preg_replace('#<br\s*/?[>](?:\s*<br\s*/?[>])+#i', '<br />', $string);
                                 ^ ^              ^ ^
```

To fix block comments, you can apply it to `/`:

```
$string = preg_replace('#<br\s*[/]?>(?:\s*<br\s*[/]?>)+#i', '<br />', $string);
                               ^ ^              ^ ^
```

To fix both comment styles, you can put `/` *and* `>` in their own character class.

**Fix using the `/x` modifier**

The `x` [modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) - aka `PCRE_EXTENDED` - ignores spaces and newlines in a regular expression (except when they occur inside a character class); this makes it possible to add spaces to separate the problematic characters. To fix both comment styles:

```
$string = preg_replace('#<br\s* /? >(?:\s*<br\s* /? >)+#ix', '<br />', $string);
                               ^  ^             ^  ^
```

Comment: @Cthulhu +1 (and for the answer too, of course). Also (at least for me) this makes the regexp a bit tougher to understand. Not by much, but If I saw this regex, I'd say: Hmmm, what's going on? But that is downright and totally subjective.

Comment: @ppeterka I somewhat agree, so I found another way, by using the `x` modifier :)

Comment: @Jack Nice, I'd give another +1 for it, I have learnt something new... I keep forgetting about the regex modifiers (I rarely use them apart from `g`)...

Comment: @Jack Thank you, I learn new things about regex from the solution.

Comment: +1 for separating the regex out onto an earlier line. It keeps the regex the same, but still allows the logic to be commented out.

Answer (score 38):

**Why your attempts didn't work:**

```
// $string = preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>(?:\s*<br\s*/?>)+#i',...
                                   ^ doesn't work due to ?> ending php

/* $string = preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>(?:\s*<br\s*/?>)+#i',... */
                                 ^ doesn't work due to */ closing comment
```

**What works:**

```
/* $string = preg_replace('#<br\s*[/]?>(?:\s*<br\s*[/]?>)+#i',... */
                                  ^ ^              ^ ^
// $string = preg_replace('#<br\s*/?[>](?:\s*<br\s*/?[>])+#i',...
                                    ^ ^              ^ ^
```

---

**Further...**

After the above, you should be able to use `/*` to comment out the line.
If you leave the `?>` intact, `//` cannot possibly comment out an entire line. The text following `?>` could be html, which is **outside the control** of the PHP interpreter, so that wouldn't work.

From **[the documentation:](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php)**

> The "one-line" comment styles only comment to the end of the line or
>   the current block of PHP code, whichever comes first. This means that
>   HTML code after // ... ?> or # ... ?> WILL be printed: ?> breaks out
>   of PHP mode and returns to HTML mode, and // or # cannot influence
>   that.

Comment: Thank you, so many things I still don't know... It's helpful.

Comment: This post would deserve far more +1s... For the thorough explanation alone.

Answer (score 15):

Another idea: Escape the `>` (and the `/`, if you want to use a `/*...*/` comment):

```
$string = preg_replace('#<br\s*\/?\>(?:\s*<br\s*\/?\>)+#i', '<br />', $string);
```

An "unnecessary" escape is ignored by the regex engine, but is useful in this case (for reasons outlined in the other answers).

Comment: @ppeterka: I used a backslash instead of a character class (but yes, I did miss one occurrence. Thanks!)

Comment: Sorry, seems I'm tired... I noticed the second one, that was left in there surrounded with []...

Answer (score 10):

Why use complicated, difficult to read "tricks" to work around the problem?

`?` is just a quantifier shortcut for convenience, so

**Just use the long version of the quantifier `{0,1}`**, means "minimum 0 maximum 1 occurrence":

```
$string = preg_replace('#<br\s*/{0,1}>(?:\s*<br\s*/{0,1}>)+#i', '<br />', $string);
```

Comment: +1 this page starts to be a very good place for gathering regex tricks to keep in the back of our minds.

Comment: @ppeterka, I would actually call all other answers "tricks", but my answer is just using the long version of the quantifier and not the shortcut.

Comment: No offense, just that in my dictionary, using the long version of an expression instead of the shorter, more convenient syntactic sugar one counts as a trick too...

Answer (score 8):

A few other ways worth adding to the *RegEx trick book*:

First you could compact your RegEx to: `/(<br\s*/?>)+/i` and replace with `<br />` (no need to burden the RegExP with lookaheads) and you'll always end up with your chosen XHMTL line break.

Other ways to modify your RegEx so it won't trip `*/` end comment or `?>` end script:

- Use [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) : `#(<br\s*+/?+>)+#i` - which basically mean for `\s*+` if you found whitespace match as many as there are and keep it, and for `/?+` if you found a slash keep it!
- Enclose `\s*` and `/*` in capture groups => `#(<br(\s*)(/?)>)+#i`

Live demos: http://codepad.viper-7.com/YjqUbi

And since we leaned the possessive behavior the fastest RegEx that also bypasses the commenting problem is: **`#(<br\s*+/?+>)++#i`** [explained demo](http://regex101.com/r/vE0rI8)

---

## As for commenting in tricky situations

When you can't change the code, or have already used a multiline comment and:

### 1. Use a **[nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)**:

```
    $string='Hello<br>World<br><br />World<br><br><br>Word!';
    <<<'comment'
    $string = preg_replace('#(<br\s*/?>)+#i', '<br />', $string);
comment;
```

Live code: http://codepad.viper-7.com/22uOtV

Note: a **nowdoc** is similar to a **heredoc** but it does not parse the content and has to have it's *starting* delimiter enclosed in `'`single quotes`'` (*note that the **ending delimiter can't be idented**, must be followed by `;` and a **new line** !*)

### 2. Jump over the code with a [goto](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php):

```
$string='Hello<br>World<br><br />World<br><br><br>Word!';
goto landing;
$string = preg_replace('#(<br\s*/?>)+#i', '<br />', $string);
landing:
```

Live example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/UfqrIQ

### 3. Jump over the code with `if(false)` or `if(0)`:

```
$string='Hello<br>World<br><br />World<br><br><br>Word!';
if(0){
$string = preg_replace('#(<br\s*/?>)+#i', '<br />', $string);
}
```

Test: http://codepad.viper-7.com/wDg5H5